# using entity farmework6 with oracle odp.net

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-6, odp.net

i use entity framework 6 with ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit
entity frameworkd version is 6.1.1 (get by NuGet)
and i use entity framework power tools beta4 create the models and mappers.

when run the program:
The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

context is:
        public partial class Context : DbContext
    {
        static Context()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(null);
        }

```
    public Context()
        : base("Name=Context")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<S_USER> S_USER { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new S_USERMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think EF 6.1 is not yet supported by oracle

Comment: @Troopers: EF 6.1 has been supported for all the older versions of ODP.NET. However, EF Code First and Code First migrations is only supported in the latest beta.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to download the latest (12.1) ODP.NET beta if you want to use EF 6 code first or code first Migrations. The 11.2.0.3.20 release does not support that.

You can get the beta here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index-2235287.html

Second of all, the error you are receiving can happen when ODP.NET is not installed properly. Certain entries must be added to the machine.config. To fix that, I would try reinstalling. Also keep in mind that there is a 32-bit and a 64-bit machine config. There should be a config tool in the ODP.NET oracle home for configuring the 64-bit machine.config if that is the target you are building. Or you can download and install the 64-bit ODP.NET which will do the same.